# creating a masked array from text fields

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) shows an example of masking existing values with `ma.masked` a posteriori (after array creation), or creating a masked array from an list of what seem to be valid data types (integer if `dtype=int`). I am trying to read in data from a file (and requires some text manipulation) but at some point I will have a list of lists (or tuples) containing strings from which I want to make a numeric (float) array.

An example of the data might be `textdata='1\t2\t3\n4\t\t6'` (typical flat text format after cleaning).

One problem I have is that missing values may be encoded as '', which when trying to convert to float using the dtype argument, will tell me

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So I've created this function

```
def makemaskedarray(X,missing='',fillvalue='-999.',dtype=float):
    arr = lambda x: x==missing and fillvalue or x    
    mask = lambda x: x==missing and 1 or 0
    triple = dict(zip(('data','mask','dtype'),
                      zip(*[(map(arr,x),map(mask,x)) for x in X])+
                      [dtype]))
    return ma.array(**triple)
```

which seems to do the trick:

```
>>> makemaskedarray([('1','2','3'),('4','','6')])
masked_array(data =
 [[1.0 2.0 3.0]
 [4.0 -- 6.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False  True False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Is this the way to do it? Or there is a built-in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it is fine. (though you could definitely make it a bit more readable by avoiding building the temporary "`triple`" dict, just to expand it a step later, i.m.o.)

The built-in way is to use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).  Depending on the amount of pre-processing you need to do to your text file, it may or may not do what you need.  However, as a basic example: (Using StringIO to simulate a file...)

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np

txt_data = """
1\t2\t3
4\t\t6
7t\8t\9"""

infile = StringIO(txt_data)
data = np.genfromtxt(infile, usemask=True, delimiter='\t')
```

Which yields:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[1.0 2.0 3.0]
 [4.0 -- 6.0]
 [7.0 8.0 9.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

One word of caution: If you do use tabs as your delimiter and an empty string as your missing value marker, you'll have issues with missing values at the start of a line.  (`genfromtxt` essentially calls `line.strip().split(delimiter)`).  You'd be better off using something like `"xxx"` as a marker for missing values, if you can.

Comment: Thanks - thought about genfromtxt but required too much pre-processing first, but thanks for the tip about missing values at the start of a line! And the StringIO trick...